# MYSQL - insert into and a null value, how to avoid?

Tags: mysql, insert, exists

I have a SQL query, it looks like that:

```
insert into tableA(order_id, contractnotenumber, shipmentdate, comment) 
    values ((select entity_id from tableb where increment_id = '12345678'), 
    '', '1970-01-01', '');
```

Now, if the subquery ((select entity_id from tableb where increment_id = '12345678')) returns null, the insert does not work. What I want is an easy way to say that if the subquery returns null, dont do anything. I tried insert ignore, but this inserts the row with 0 instead of null, which works, but its not what I want. In SQL Server I used *if not exists(select...)*, but this does not work with MYSQL.

Ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into tableA(order_id, contractnotenumber, shipmentdate, comment)
select entity_id, '', '1970-01-01', '' from tableb where increment_id = '12345678'
```

This won't insert anything if the row isn't found in `tableb`

Comment: Hmmm, somehow the query runs forever...some detail missing? The select itself returns data though.

Comment: @EOB: in this query `INSERT` inserts what `SELECT` selected. If it returned nothing - then insert immediately "exits"

Comment: Yeah, the exit works but if something exists, it runs and runs and runs until I either cancel it or until I get a timeout.

Comment: Ah, my fault, I had some other transaction running from my previous tries and it blocked the new query! **Solved!**

Answer (score 0):

You could also try mysql> insert ignore

Comment: As I said, this does not work in my case, it will insert the row with 0 for the id, which is not what I want.